# <HttpPost()> doesn't work in my view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have two links say for eg. English and Spanish. When user clicks on english link it should set language to "English" in session.

The following is my aspx code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">
function SetLanguageSpanish() {
    document.getElementById("Home_Language").value = 'Spanish';   
      document.getElementById("frmHome").submit();
  }
    function SetLanguageEnglish() {    
    /*var obj = document.getElementById("LangEnglish");*/
        //             <% Session("Language") = "English"%>;
        document.getElementById("Home_Language").value = 'English';
        document.getElementById("frmHome").submit();
    }
</script>

<div class="vmenu">

<form id="frmHome" action="Home" method="post"">

<a id="LangEnglish" href="/" onclick="SetLanguageEnglish();" >English</a>
<a id="LangSpanish" href="/" onclick="SetLanguageSpanish();"> Spanish</a>
<h3><%= Html.Label(Model.SubTitle) %></h3>

<ul class="sbe">
    <li class="sbe"><a href="/test1"><%= Model.Menu1%></a></li>
    <li class="sbe"><a href="/Test2"><%= Model.Menu2%></a></li>
    <li class="sbe"><a href="/Test3"><%= Model.Menu3%></a></li>
    <li class="sbe"><a href="/Test4"><%= Model.Menu4%></a></li>
    <li class="sbe"><a href="/Test5"><%= Model.Menu5%></a></li>    
</ul>

<input id="Home_PageName" name="PageName" type="hidden" value="" />
<input id="Home_Language" name="Language" type="hidden" value="" />

<input id="Home_PageTitle" name="PageTitle" type="hidden" value="" />
<input id="Home_SubTitle" name="SubTitle" type="hidden" value="" />

<input id="Home_Menu1" name="Menu1" type="hidden" value="" />
<input id="Home_Menu2" name="Menu2" type="hidden" value="" />
<input id="Home_Menu3" name="Menu3" type="hidden" value="" />
<input id="Home_Menu4" name="Menu4" type="hidden" value="" />
<input id="Home_Menu5" name="Menu5" type="hidden" value="" />

</form>

</div>

</asp:Content>
```

and my controller class code is as follow:

Public Class HomeController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

```
' GET: /Home
<OutputCache(Duration:=1800, VaryByParam:="none")>
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Try
        Dim oHome As New Home.Home
        Dim oHomeModel As New Home.HomeVM

        If (HttpContext.Session("Language") Is Nothing) Then
            HttpContext.Session("Language") = "English"
        End If

        oHomeModel.Language = HttpContext.Session("Language").ToString()

        Return View("Index", GetCaption(oHomeModel))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function


<HttpPost()>
<OutputCache(Duration:=1800)>
Function Index(ByVal oHomeModel As Home.HomeVM) As ActionResult
    Try
        If ((oHomeModel.Language IsNot Nothing) Or (oHomeModel.Language.ToString() <> "")) Then
            HttpContext.Session("Language") = oHomeModel.Language.ToString()
        End If
        Return View("Index", GetCaption(oHomeModel))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

**For some reason when i click on any link on my view page. The Controller class get is getting fired. due to this the value in session is not getting refreshed. Can anyone suggest why this is happening?**

The following is my model class.

Namespace Home
        Public Class HomeVM

```
    'The following property are used as parameter
    Public Property PageName As String
    Public Property Language As String

    'The following are the form caption peroperty
    Public Property PageTitle As String
    Public Property SubTitle As String

    Public Property Menu1 As String
    Public Property Menu2 As String
    Public Property Menu3 As String
    Public Property Menu4 As String
    Public Property Menu5 As String


End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you are mixing up server side and client side code.

```
<% Session("Language") = "English"%>;
```

The above line you have in JavaScript gets executed when the page first loads which prints nothing to the page. If you look at the source you should see nothing other than the semi-colon `;`.

When you click the link that calls `SetLanguageSpanish()` there is nothing to be executed in that function and the page is directed to '/'. Have a look at the page source.

**Edit**

Here is some updated code which will submit a hidden input with the id "language" and a value of the specified by the function parameter.

**HTML**

```
<form id="frmHome" method="post">
    <a href="#" onclick="SetLanguage('English');">English</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="SetLanguage('Spanish');"> Spanish</a>
    <input type="hidden" id="language" name="language" value="" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function SetLanguage(language) {
    document.getElementById("language").value = language;
    document.getElementById("frmHome").submit();
}
```

**VB.NET** *I am not a VB guy so double check the syntax here*

```
<HttpPost()>
<OutputCache(Duration:=1800)>
Function Index(ByVal language As string) As ActionResult

    HttpContext.Session("Language") = language

    'Do stuff

    Return this.View()
End Function
```

Comment: even if i remove the scripting code still post doesn't happen.

Comment: @VinodNair it sounds like you are saying that you want to `POST` when the user clicks the link so you can change the selected language. If that is the case, the first problem you have is that they are links and do not cause a post-back. To cause a post-back in your function you can `document.getElementById("frmHome").submit();` but you will also want to set a value to be submitted before posting so you can read it ion the server

Comment: @VinodNair already edited the answer and posted a solution. You'll have to handle the server side code to retrieve the the language from the posted hidden input and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks for the code but my problem of submiting the page(postback) still exist. It is not invoking HttpPost() method

Comment: @VinodNair I am assuming that you mean it is not invoking the action that is decorated with HttpPost and not a method called HttpPost so what happened exactly when you click the link?

Comment: It invokes ' GET: /Home
        <OutputCache(Duration:=1800, VaryByParam:="none")>
        Function Index() As ActionResult

Comment: @VinodNair I updated the answer to include a controller action that would accept a `POST`. Double check the syntax because I am not a C# guy. I missed the `name` attribute on the hidden `input` and updated that as well.

Comment: I tried the modified code but the problem still exist. When i click on my "link" in view page it invokes the get() action for the first and continues to do for the second time also after that if you keep clicking for the fourth time it invokes post action. if I keep clicking the link again neither get nor post action gets invoked.

Comment: @VinodNair It sounds to me like you didn't update your markup with the HTML I provided OR you have a JavaScript error that is causing a problem. Make sure your links are in the form `<a href="#" onclick="SetLanguage('English');">English</a>` and not the way you had them originally.

Comment: Thanks Craig. You were right. i updated the javascript and it worked. Thanks for your help Craig.